# Changing colors for an image in website

Tags: javascript, php, css, jsp

how to partition an image in a website ? like this web site (each image is able to change her colors) : http://www.zolpan-intensement-couleurs.fr/fr/simulateur/decorateur_virtuel/index.aspx ,  what is the language that can we use ?

Comment: This page was created in flash. You can create it using that or using any modern javascript/jquery.

Comment: thanks, i'll search for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an image, it's a flash animation. Color-changing and other animations are also possible with [pure CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) or with Javascript.